# Windows Command line c file compile error

Tags: c

I work with C codes using gcc compiler and Clion IDE

So, I have a `src` folder for `.c` codes and `include` folder of `.h` files which contains a bunch of #define

I include some of the `.h` files in my main.c programe

when I run it in my Clion project, everything work fine

but when I try to run with command line (cuz I need command arguments), it says

`Fatal Error: MyFunction.h, no such file or directory` `MyFunction.h` IS MY FILE, NOT DEFAULT library file

What I typed in the command line is `$gcc C:\Users\Admin\CLionProjects\project\src\main.c`

What I get is `"C:\Users\Admin\CLionProjects\project\src\main.c 10: Fatal Error: MyFunction.h No such file or directory.`

Then I try to change the `#include <MyFunction.h>` to `#include "MyFunction.h"`, hoping it will solve the problem, but no.

Then I did a test, I call a function of another `.c` file in the same `src` folder, and use command line to run `main.c`, but it tells me the function is not even defined.

cmd can recognized all the default library files like `stdio.h`, but none of those created by me. Any idea how to solve this problem? I know it must be some kind of path error

Comment: Could you show us how do you compile in command line? What is the command?

Comment: Is `****.h` a file you wrote or is it part of a system library? Is it in the same directory as your c file?

Comment: I did try put it in the same folder as the main.c, but somehow cmd still does not recognize it, as I had mentioned. cmd does not even recognize the function from another c file in the same src folder. I don't have any error or warning when working in IDE, IDE recognize these files, but cmd doesn't.

Comment: Are you compiling from a different working directory than where the source files are? The use of a full absolute path kind of suggests that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell `gcc` preprocessor where to find files you want to include.

You have two kinds of header:

- System headers: included with `#include <header>`.
- Local headers: included with `#include "header"`.

Preprocessor searchs in **header search path** to find system headers.
Preprocessor searchs in current directory, then in header path to find local headers.

You can add folders in **header search path** using `-I` option in `gcc` invocation.

So in your case, you can compile with these commands:

```
$gcc -I C:\Users\Admin\CLionProjects\project\include C:\Users\Admin\CLionProjects\project\src\main.c
```

or

```
$cd C:\Users\Admin\CLionProjects\project\src
$gcc -I ..\include main.c
```